# Package Manager not in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, package-control

I had originally used the code given at https://packagecontrol.io/installation to install package manager when I upgraded to Sublime 3.
Now although the Package Control.sublime-package file is in Installed Packages, there is no way for me to access package manager (i.e. Ctrl + Shift + P) doesn't give it as an options.

Comment: Are there any errors in the ST console on start up?

Comment: No, everything there looks good.

Comment: Hmm odd, do you see a line like `reloading plugin Package Control.Package Control` in the console? If not, it's possible something went wrong with the original install of package control.

Comment: What about these:
`reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.00-package_control`
`reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.02-bz2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I tried reinstalling Sublime. It didn't change anything, but I then went in and deleted the Sublime Text 3 folder, which contained package manager files and package files. 
This file wasn't changed during the reinstall. 
I then was able to start from scratch, reinstall package manager and can now use it properly.